# How i can sum quantity if increase and decrease quantity?

Tags: php, mysql

**How i can sum quantity if increase and decrease quantity?**

**Table *Product_stock***
[image]

**sql statement**

```
SELECT SUM(product_stock_quantity) AS total From product_stock GROUP BY product_stock_status
```

I would like results is

> TOTAL 100-50 = 50

I Don't know to sum quantity when multi row records if increase and decrease quantity.Please help me.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just store the value as a positive or negative number? Now you have to use some inefficient if statement on the column and sum that. You would likely be best off now selecting everythiing in two separate queries and subtracting the `-` from the `+`. This could be combined into one query but it would still be two separate (possibly correlated) sub-queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just sum:

```
SELECT SUM(product_stock_quantity*IF(product_stock_status = '-',-1,1)) AS total From product_stock
```

ps.: don't group!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would store the stock as a negative number, but for the way you have it stored you can do this.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN product_stock_status = '-' THEN -1 * product_stock_quantity ELSE product_stock_quantity) AS total From product_stock GROUP BY product_stock_status
```

Comment: Yes didn't see what the group by was haha, if it was a category or something that makes sense but not by sign. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes I'm not sure what realy result he want.